# how to *start* a process with a high priority

Tags: linux, nice

Notes: 
 1. by lower priority I mean that the priority *number* is lower.
 2. Distro is RHE

I want to start a daemon with lower than normal priority (ie. say  18 rather than 20) so it will get cpu first in the case of contention.

nice runs commands at increased priority, renice can raise or lower but works for processes that are already running.

I would rather not have to dig the pid out of the process list and then call renice in the start script if I can avoid it since the program does not conveniently produce a pid file.

Comment: Which major RHEL release, 6 or 7?

Comment: Are you really that CPU constrained at this point? You should be careful of this type of design because there may be unintended consequences.

Comment: What @HBruijn said.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of the dangers.  In this case I have a daemon (radium) that collects data over the network and every hour compresses the last hours data.  The compress jobs were hogging the cpu and I was loosing data because radium is not reading it fast enough.    I am keeping an eye on it to make sure the compress jobs finish before the next run ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just launch it with nice.

E.g.:

> nice -n 18 /path/to/mydaemon

Comment: Ah Thanks! that works fine.  I was mislead by man page that states:
 -n, --adjustment=N
              add integer N to the niceness (default 10)
where as it seems not to reflect reality ???  This whole thing with "niceness" and "priority" is confusing

Answer (score 7):

Additionally, you can use the ionice command to start the process with low io priority:

```
nice -n18 ionice -c3 /path/to/mydaemon
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, I thought positive numbers in nice reduce the CPU of an app, and negative make it faster?  So to increase the prio / CPU I use **negative** integers to raise prio in clementine (audio player) with renice:

```
sudo renice -5 $(pgrep clementine)
```

Comment: That's true, but instead of posting another question you should edit the existing question instead.